# to get the values from string tokenizer

Tags: java, string

I have written the code to spit the string i.e birthdate,I want to store it in 3 different vaiables how to do it. (Mday=1,Mmonth=1,MYear=2011).I am getting birtdate dynamically.also I am getting values in token.

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(BirtDate, "/");
                while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String token = st.nextToken();
                    System.out.println("Token = " + token);
                }
```

Comment: what input you are giving? what is the problem in your code?

Comment: String 1/11/2011 I am getting values in token when I am printing.But I want to store them

Comment: and what is the problem with your code?

Comment: No problem in the code how to store that values which are in token in variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One better way could be to use date formatter and object as below:

```
     DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
     Date date = format.parse("1/1/2012");
     //Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     cal.setTime(date);
     int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);//You may want to add 1
     int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     int year= cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Please note: Month starts from 0, so you may want to add 1.

Comment: int day = ((Calendar) date).get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); Cannot cast from Date to Calendar giving error

Comment: because I am getting The method get(int) is undefined for the type Date

Comment: @user1758835: My bad, updated the answer. Please note, month starts from 0, so you may want to add 1.

Answer (score 2):

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String 
>   or the java.util.regex package instead

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Use instead

```
String[] token = BirtDate.split("/")
```